# Pass derived type as array

Tags: arrays, fortran, derived-types

In Fortran, one can operate on arrays, but how can one treat the indices of a derived type as part of an array too? Code would explain what I want to do best:

```
type mytype
    integer :: b(3,3)
    real :: c(4)
endtype

integer :: a(3,3)
real :: d(2,4)
type(mytype) :: mat(2)

!do stuff so that 'mat' gets values
....

!usually one does this
a = matmul(mat(1)%b, transpose(mat(2)%b))

!multiplying two 3x3 matrices

!but how does one do this? Note the "array"
d = matmul(mat(:)%c, mat(:)%c)
```

I assumed that the final line is analogous to a 2x4 matrix being multiplied with itself. However, when I try to compile, gfortran complains

> Error: Two or more part references with nonzero rank must not be specified

Is this possible to do in Fortran?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want the compiler to regard `mat(:)%c` as a 2 x 4 matrix?   It doesn't work that way.   `mat` and `c` are different objects and their ranks don't merge into a single array.  `mat` is a user-defined type and `c` is a real matrix.  Just because you are only using the `c`-component of `mat` doesn't mean the compiler will promote `c` to a higher dimensional real array, based on the dimension of `mat`.

You could create a new array via `X = [ mat(1)%c, mat(2)%c ]`.   You could use `reshape` to control the shape.

Answer (score 3):

You can't multiply nonsquare matrices by themselves. You have to transpose one of them.

You also mix reals and integers. Your matrices are supposed to be real and your result is integer.

It's possible to reference the matrix with a small FORTRAN STYLE hack (equivalence and sequence, assuming same storage size for default integer and real). This one compiles :))))

```
type mytype
    !!!
    sequence
    integer :: b(3,3)
    real :: c(4)
endtype

integer :: a(3,3)
real :: d(4,4)

type(mytype) :: mat(2)
real,dimension(13,2) :: newmat

!!!
equivalence (mat,newmat)

!do stuff so that 'mat' gets values
! ....

!usually one does this
a = matmul(mat(1)%b, mat(2)%b)

!multiplying two 3x3 matrices

!but how does one do this? Note the "array"
 d = matmul(reshape(newmat(10:13,:),(/4,2/)),transpose(reshape(newmat(10:13,:),(/4,2/))))

end
```

Comment: Fortran programmer must be prepared to find similar things in legacy codes :). Nevertheless the first two messages were more important and still apply. The code is just for fun.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors. I've fixed them. The heart of the question remains the same, though.

Comment: You put the transpose in the wrong row. The first multiplication is ok. Also check for the correct dimension of the result. The correct answer is M.S.B's, my example doesn't save anything in terms of memory, reshape and transpose generate a temporary array anyway. It was just to illustrate the equivalence.